# Weird behaviour from pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I was testing ways to append data to a pandas data frame (first time using pandas so I was trying different ways out, I KNOW THE FIRST WAY IS BETTER.) but I ran this code to test both methods and it would run perfectly the first time but the second time it would create a 5th column where the data was processed perfectly but it was only in that 5th column.
P.S. the big hello world list was 100 rows long but I just chopped them off for here.

```
    def evaluate(self, data):
        real_data = list(map(lambda x: x[1], data))
        full_data = [data[i] + self.plugin_funcs(x) for i,x in enumerate(real_data)]
        # print(full_data)
        # print(self.df.columns)
        df_data = pd.DataFrame(full_data, columns=list(self.df.columns))
        # print(df_data)
        self.df = pd.concat([self.df, df_data])
        # print(self.df)

    def evaluate2(self, data):
        for row in data:
            eval_data = [row + self.plugin_funcs(row[1])]
            # print(len(eval_data[0]))
            self.df = self.df._append(eval_data[0])
        pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
        print(self.df)

def test_func(string):
    return string.split(":")
int_func = {"func":test_func, "head": ["data1", "data2"]}
ser = serial.Serial("COM3")
pog = reader(int_func, ser)
times1 = 0
times2 = 0
data = [['TIME', 'Hello:world'], ['TIME2', 'Hello:world2'], ['TIME3', 'Hello:world3'],...]
for _ in range(2):
    for i, func in enumerate([pog.evaluate, pog.evaluate2]):
        str_time = time.time()
        func(data)
        end_time = time.time()
        if i == 0:
            times1 += (str_time - end_time)
        else:
            times2 += (str_time - end_time)
    print(pog.df.columns)

print(f"Times1:{(times1/1000)}")
print(f"Times2:{(times2/1000)}")
```

I made it so you don't need my other classes. This time it does it the first time around weirdly

```
import time

import pandas as pd


def evaluate(data, df, func):
        real_data = list(map(lambda x: x[1], data))
        full_data = [data[i] + func(x) for i,x in enumerate(real_data)]
        # print(full_data)
        # print(self.df.columns)
        df_data = pd.DataFrame(full_data, columns=list(df.columns))
        # print(df_data)
        df = pd.concat([df, df_data])
        # print(self.df)

def evaluate2(data, df, funcs):
    for row in data:
        eval_data = [row + funcs(row[1])]
        eval_data = eval_data[0]
        # print(len(eval_data[0]))
        df = df._append(eval_data)
    pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
    print(df)

def test_func(string):
    return string.split(":")
pog = pd.DataFrame(columns=["time", "raw", "data1", "data2"])

times1 = 0
times2 = 0
data = [['TIME', 'Hello:world'], ['TIME2', 'Hello:world2'], ['TIME3', 'Hello:world3'],...
for _ in range(2):
    for i, func in enumerate([evaluate, evaluate2]):
        str_time = time.time()
        func(data, pog,test_func)
        end_time = time.time()
        if i == 0:
            times1 += (str_time - end_time)
        else:
            times2 += (str_time - end_time)
    print(pog.columns)

print(f"Times1:{(times1/1000)}")
print(f"Times2:{(times2/1000)}")
```

Comment: `_append` is a **private** method, there is no guarantee of behavior, nor of existence. You should **not use it**. Especially to have a quadratic running time behavior...